# Foreign Key в PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть таблица

```
create table groups (
   id serial primary key,
   parent_id integer not null REFERENCES groups(id),
   name varchar not null,
)
```

Бывают такие группы, когда parent_id должен ссылаться на текущий id. Вопрос в том, как при добавлении новой группы сделать parent_id равный id, не прибегая к допзапросу с клиента.

Comment: not null лишний

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне тоже кажется немного странной идея делать `parent_id = id`. Но сделать можно.

В принципе достаточно знать, что не существует типа данных `serial` - это лишь синтаксическая обёртка над `int default nextval(sequence_name)` и соответствующий `sequence`. Соответственно можно отдельно вызвать `nextval` и спокойно использовать значение:

```
insert into groups (id, parent_id, name)
    select nid, nid, 'имя группы' 
    from nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('groups', 'id')) as nid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что у вас `parent_id` не может быть пустым значением `null`. В таком случае, при добавлении группы, которая должна ссылаться сама на себя возникнет ошибка, так как группы еще нет, и у нее нет идентификатора. Думаю, что без подзапроса тут не обойтись, так как вам нужно знать идентификатор.

Дання схема данных вызывает проблемы, так как она составлена не совсем корректно. Для начала, если у вас таблица `groups` пустая, то туда нельзя вставить строк, так как ограничение `not null REFERENCES` мягко говоря будет мешать. Я бы рекомендовал изменить схему данных. В текущем виде ваша таблица будет доставлять вам только неудобства.

Было бы логично сделать `parent_id` допускающим значение `null`, и считать, что если в этой колонке `null` - то таблица ссылается сама на себя. Возможно не самое лучшее решение, но это избавит вас от некоторых проблем. Конечно, нужно не забывать про то, что нужно внести изменения в зависящий от этой схемы данных код.

Ну и для справки:

- [PostgreSql Внешние ключи (Foreign Keys)](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/tutorial-fk.html)
- [postgresql foreign key syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28560619/5275890)
- [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46415)